# FormParameter doesn't work correctly

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I wrote this code to take a message information from HTML fields, and then executes insert command. but InsertCommand didn't execute. What's the problem here ?

```
<form action="FormParameter.aspx" method="post">
<label >Title :</label>
<input id="txtTitle" type="text" /><br />
<label >Subject:</label>
<input id="txtSubject" type="text" /><br />
<label >Category: </label>
<input id="txtCategory" type="text" /><br />

<input id="btnAdd" type="submit" value="Add" />

</form>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MessagesConnectionString %>" 

        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Messages] ([Title], [Subject], [CategoryID]) VALUES (@Title, @Subject, @CategoryID)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Messages]" >

        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter Name="Title" FormField="txtTitle" DefaultValue="No Title" />
            <asp:FormParameter  Name="Subject" FormField="txtSubject" DefaultValue="No Subject" />
            <asp:FormParameter Name="CategoryID" FormField="txtCategory" DefaultValue="No Category" />
        </InsertParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the codeFile (FormParameter.aspx.cs)

```
void Page_Load()
{

    if (Request.Form["btnAdd"] != null)
        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using the ASP.NET sever controls?

Comment: Why -1 !! what's your problem ?

Comment: Don't know who downvoted, but personally "something new" seems to be a rather bad reason to do something that seems to be much more complicated and non-standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have add a form that call the FormParameter.aspx. This can not work like that, manually.

So keep one form only and place there all the controls, and there the post back will work correctly.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<label >Title :</label>
<input id="txtTitle" type="text" /><br />
<label >Subject:</label>
<input id="txtSubject" type="text" /><br />
<label >Category: </label>
<input id="txtCategory" type="text" /><br />

<input id="btnAdd" type="submit" value="Add" />

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MessagesConnectionString %>" 

        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Messages] ([Title], [Subject], [CategoryID]) VALUES (@Title, @Subject, @CategoryID)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Messages]" >

        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter Name="Title" FormField="txtTitle" DefaultValue="No Title" />
            <asp:FormParameter  Name="Subject" FormField="txtSubject" DefaultValue="No Subject" />
            <asp:FormParameter Name="CategoryID" FormField="txtCategory" DefaultValue="No Category" />
        </InsertParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
```

and on code behind is better to use

```
void Page_Load()
{
    if (IsPostBack)
        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
}
```

There is a way to make your code work, by disable the validation for this page, but you make then your page vulnerable to attacks.

Now I see again your code and I am not so sure that InsertParametres can get the values of non server controls, I think that you also need to change them to ServerControls.

Comment: The message information is not taken except when i was changing HTML elements to ServerControls! why ?

Comment: @WasimAlatrash because that is the way the SqlDataSource work.